# Is polynomial written in this form ring?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

We have polynomial written as $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^{i}$, the question is, is it a ring for $n≤3$?

Comment: A first step is to know if the sum and the product are internal laws in the  polynomials with degree $\leq 3$. If not, this set cannot be a ring. What do you think about the product ?

Comment: The question "Is polynomial a ring" does not make much sense. Did you mean to ask whether *the set of all( such polynomials forms a ring?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:  Rings are closed under multiplication.  Degrees add when polynomials multiply.

Comment: Sorry but i really don't understand "closed under multiplication".

Comment: If $R(+, \cdot)$ is a ring and $x, y \in R$, we must have $x \cdot y \in R$.

Comment: Negative numbers are not closed under multiplication because when you multiply them the result is not negative.

Comment: But what if our $R$ is some set of all polynomials with integer coefficients, and our polynomial is written in form of sum, where $ n \in N_{0}$?